# MathJax \newcommand appears persistent across the whole page

Tags: discussion, mathjax

Probably this is known.

MathJax `\newcommand` appears to be persistent
across the whole page, including the question + all answers.

This potentially might cause some mischief.

Trying to redefine `\mathbb` in the answers.

Before redefinition:  $\mathbb{N}$.

$\newcommand{mathbb}[1]{\text{;-) }#1}$

After: $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: That's a well known issue $\Bbb N$ ;-)

Comment: How many of you wanted to post a Dothraki "It is known" meme after reading this? ;-)

Comment: I don't claim it is a bug $\newcommand{mathbf}[1]{\text{;-) }#1}$. What about comments? :-)

Comment: @Manishearth: I don't follow memes, and have no idea what that meme is about. (I did follow the seasons of GoT though, so I know what Dothraki is.)

Comment: IMO, usage of newcommand and related should be discouraged/blocked altogether. This is somehow off-topic here, but I always wanted to say it and this is the best occassion so far.

Comment: @quid, I am sorry but... why? Have you tried to compose an answer which contains a couple of dozens of `\mathbb{R}` and or many `\operatorname{Ext}`?!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: it might be that it is less relevant for things I write, but not completely so. I do not know which of my answers contains most formulas to check. But, since some years (I did this differently before, it's not that I don't know how to do it), I write most of my papers without or essentially without (especially if I have coauthors), which applies on MO, one reason. And, if you write so complicated answers you might use an editor and then run a replace. But I know I'm in the minority here. Also it is irritating while MathJax compiles. And, for reason just brought up.

Comment: Previously discussed on Meta.Math.SE: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page

Comment: So, if an answer contains `\newcommand\RR{\mathbb{R}}`, another contains `\newcommand\RR{\mathcal{R}}`, and a third uses `\RR` without defining it, the symbol shown in the third answer depends on the order in which the previous answers are visualized? Sounds tricky.

Comment: This was [changed in January 2019](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4130/the-scope-of-newcommand-is-the-entire-page/29621#29621), now the scope is a single post (or a single comment). This is related to this change: [Problem with posts and comments relying on macros defined elsewhere](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4103).

Answer (score 2):

This is known

Answers which abuse this can obviously be flagged (or edited, though a flag alerts a moderator who may then give a strict warning to the user)

In fact, there are a bunch of other ways you can use mathjax abusively. Flag if you see it happening.

Comment: What about comments ;-)

Comment: Just a pointer: for legitimate situations (where two users use custom macros with identical names), there's the begingroup extension (via \require) http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#begingroup

Comment: @peter not necessary, newcommand overwrites itself if used twice in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Just testing mathbb.

`\mathbb{N}`==$\mathbb{N}$

...and

`\mathbf{N}`==$\mathbf{N}$